# Apostrophe instead of the first sound. Where do I read about it?

Tags: pronunciation, apostrophe, contractions

What sources are there about rules for such contractions in American English when the first sound of the word isn’t pronounced.

There’s an apostrophe or something like this instead.

F/e, the Chicago Manual of Style mentions a certain Webster’s list.

Comment: Can you provide an example?

Comment: 'Merica being the most relevant one

Comment: 'Possum is another good example.

Comment: Requests for sources of information are off topic. This should be moved to the meta site.

Comment: If you asked instead, "what are the rules for pronouncing words that start with an apostrophe?" or something like that, it might make an OK question for this site.

Comment: @PeterShor *Possum* itself is listed in dictionaries.

Answer (score -1):

Used in forms like 'Merica for America or 'Em for Them, these are slang,  colloquialisms and/or patois that differ by definition from standard language usage.  Therefore I would try the Urban Dictionary or [Green's Dictionary of Slang](https://greensdictofslang.com/)

Answer (score -2):

It is a case of the broader phenomenon called [Elision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elision).

> In some languages employing the Latin alphabet, such as English, the omitted letters in a contraction are replaced by an apostrophe (e.g., isn't for is not).

Included in the list [Examples of elision in English](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elision#English):

> Word     IPA before elision     IPA after elision
>     him                /hɪm/                       /ɪm/